# Ubuntu server 15.04, Only can boot in Recovery mode (display -UNCLAIMED)

Tags: boot, grub2, 15.04

I am a newbie to the Ubuntu, I have just bought an IBM X3100 M5 and installed Ubuntu 15.04 via USB drive. Everything is smooth during the installation process, after the installation done i was asked to remove the USB and continue to restart.

Upon restart The system unable to boot my newly installed Ubuntu.
Just for your info:
I have changed my boot order priority to my SATA HDD drive.
and even manually selected the SATA drive to boot.

but it shown a black screen with "underscore" flashing on the top left of my monitor.

I tried to access to GRUB but failed even I was pressing "shift" from the beginning upon reboot.

Following is the boot repair link:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/11707450/

After repair using boot repair, i managed to boot it in recovery mode. lshw -c display shown: unclaimed.
If i run it in normal mode it will turned black screen again.

How to get the display problem solved?

Thanks in advance for your help.!!

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a graphics card issue.

Try this:

1. Reboot in recovery mode.
2. Go to System Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers
3. Select the driver that matches your graphic card.

Comment: You should purge your previous driver first. For example, if the nvidia driver was giving trouble, do 'sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia' and then install the native xorg driver.

Answer (score 0):

Try boot repair tool:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Perhaps that will solve the issue.

Comment: i have tried with boot repair and get the following link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11707450/

Comment: Did you note this in the result:
> The boot of your PC is in EFI mode, but no EFI partition was detected. You may want to retry after creating a EFI partition (FAT32, 100MB~250MB, start of the disk, boot flag).
Do you want to continue?

Comment: i managed to get into GRUB after the repair and  can boot it ONLY in the (recovery mode),  my further check lshw -c display shown: Display UNCLAIMED. appreciate any help